# How to make shortcuts to executables

Tags: root, shortcuts, executable

I'm a little bit noob. I can run a program in terminal with;

```
$sudo /opt/eclipse/eclipse
```

but I don't know how to create a shortcut that starts it with root privileges (They are installed in /opt so it needs root)

Comment: "They are installed in /opt so it needs root" is wrong. There are reasons why a program would need to run as root, but this is usually not one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ALL** of the default programs which come preinstalled with Ubuntu or which can be installed from repositories are "installed as root" in system directories, yet you do not need to superuser privileges to run them.

You're confusing the permissions necessary to read/execute a program with permissions necessary to override or delete the file. The program file may be owned by `root`, but if your user has execute privileges, you'll be able to run the program. The running process will have User ID of your user, so it won't be able to modify files owned by `root`.

This is an important security measure and running with super-user privileges should be reserved only for a small set of trusted applications which actually require this (i.e. the ones which make change to system configuration (Software Center and Update Manager) or directly access hardware devices (gparted).

Eclipse **does not** require root privileges regardless of whether it is installed in `/opt` or in your home directory (which I personally prefer). What's probably happening is that you started it as `root` the first time so the directory in your home folder which stores Eclipse configuration (`home/(yourusername)/.eclipse`) is owned by `root`. You need to change the directory's owner to give Eclipse to write there when started as non-privileged user:

```
chown -R yourusername:yourusername ~/.eclipse
```

Comment: Thanks.Appriciated.It gave me an error "cant acces workplace" or sth when I try to run as a normal user.Now i got it.I shouldn't have installed it with "sudo" in the first place.I guess I just didnt want it to be installed in my home directory.

Comment: If you install a program into `/opt` you *have* to use `sudo`, there's nothing wrong with that. What you shouldn't do is to start the program with `sudo`, especially the first time - on first startup it creates a number of directories and config files which are owned by `root`, so on subsequent startups the program won't be able to access those files, which is likely the cause of the error messages you see.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the easiest way is just making a shell script.  What ever command you use to launch eclipse use the same.

You probably want to use "gksudo" and then your command which looks like

gksudo /opt/eclipse/eclipse

Then put that in a regular file with a .sh extension.  Right click the file and add execution permissions.  You can also use chmod +x filename.sh

Here is a good tutorial to get you the basics of bash scripts.  Its really easy and powerful.

http://linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial

I haven't tried launching eclipse from the command line, but I believe it is built with java.  If that is the case you might also need to specify java -jar in there some where, but I'm not sure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: While this answers the OP's question, the question itself has been based on misunderstanding, so the answer is rather harmful than helpful.

Comment: I don't agree.  The asker wanted to know how to make a short cut.  Not your definition of how to make a short cut.

Comment: It's 2024 and I'm on Ubuntu 23.10 now (the worst version I've used in 19 years of Ubuntu). Inkscape crashes and the only fix for the moment is to run with sudo. So yes, this is an important answer while we're hoping that we get a fix soon.